# Angular: How to debug Karma unit tests when Babel transpiling is used?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, babeljs

I use JetBrains Webstorm for a while now and it really shines when debugging Karma unit tests for e.g. Angular webapps.

But I am stuck at trying to debug unit tests when the sources are **transpiled via Babel**. I decided to run the tests on the transpiled sources instead of the original ES6 compatible ones just to be sure that everything works which works in Babel, which is more than e.g. Chrome can handle.

But how can I set breakpoints in the ES6 files which actually fire when Karma hits them on the transpiled version? Does Karma honor source maps? I could not get it to work. Has someone tried on this task and give me some hints how to configure the whole thing?

Summary:

- working: run Karma unit tests on transpiled source files
- **not** workin: breakpoints/debugging unit tests